# Execute JavaScript code from String (pure JS)

Tags: javascript

I know, that there are already similar topics on SO, and the answer to them is usually "you can use `eval()`, but you shouldn't do this". Great answer, but anyway `eval()` doesn't solve my problem. Let's say I have a `String` var called `string_code`:

```
var GLOBAL_TEST= 'it works';
alert(GLOBAL_TEST);
```

Now I need to execute it. Note, that it should also define `GLOBAL_TEST`, so it can be used later on. Using jQuery, I do it like this:

```
$('body').append('<script>'+string_code+'</script>');
```

Now, how to do it in pure JS?

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document#Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document#Methods)

Comment: Doing this is actually no safer than using eval. The reason eval is dangerous is because it executes what could be potentially volatile code. Any content from outside your script might contain dangerous code which may compromise the sites security. By creating a script like this, the browser runs the code just like you could using eval. Any dangerous code would still get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simply create the `<script>` element and set its `innerHTML` property, then append it to the body:

```
var s;
s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerHTML = 'alert("works");';
//or in your case
//s.innerHTML = string_code;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Just be aware that this is generally considered a bad practice, adding scripts dynamically is usually done with external scripts along the lines of:

```
var s;
s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'path/to/script.js';
s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function () {...};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the reason the OP's code didn't work. It's because the line `$('body').append('<script>'+string_code+'</script>');` causes the HTML parser to end the script prematurely. Your code doesn't have the closing script tag in it, so it's OK

Comment: @JuanMendes, OP never said his code didn't work, he simply asked how it would be done without jQuery.